# Comparing lists and taking elements from one list that contain elements of other list

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

I have two lists, A and B.

```
A = ["string1", "string2"]
B = ["A string1 W", "B string4 Q", "HF string2 W]
```

I'd like to find a way to compare both lists and take the elements from B that contain strings from A, and put these elements in another text file list. The above example would yield:

```
C = ["A string1 W", "HF string2 W"]
```

Thanks in advdance for any help!

Note: The question initially involved reading lines from text files, but since that part was trivial I chose to remove it.

Comment: https://sopython.com/wiki/What_tutorial_should_I_read%3F

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is pretty simple, and frankly some additional googling should have gotten you there. However you can do this quite succinct using,

```
# read lines as a list
file_1_lines = open('/path/to/file1').readlines()
file_2_lines = open('/path/to/file2').readlines()

# get the containing lines with a list comp
file_2_lines_containing_1 = [file_2_lines[i] for i in range(len(file_2_lines)) if file_1_lines[i] in file_2_lines[i]]

# save
with open('/path/to/newfile') as f:
    json.dump(file_2_lines_containing_1,f)
```

If you would like a for-loop implementation that is simpler, comment.

Comment: I'm getting an empty list for "file_2_lines_containing_1" - is there something that I can add to the code to make it work? I know the issue isn't newline characters in A.txt, since I removed those in the list (for cases where the string in A.txt is not at the end of a line in B.txt).

Comment: You probably have new line characters in the original list. Clean the entries

Comment: No, I'm certain that I don't have newline characters in "file_2_lines" since when I print the list I don't see newline characters. I used "file_2_lines = list(map(lambda s: s.strip(), file_2_lines))" to remove the newlines

Comment: So what you have there still isn't working for me, but I used the following code instead of the sixth line there and it worked: "file_2_lines_containing_1 = [i for e in file_2_lines for i in file_1_lines if e in i]".